# How to use List<T>() to hide private fields?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, oop, properties

I created a DatesClass where I get Date data from, this data is stored in strings (for some reason -- I know I could've just used DateTime --) inside a Microsoft SQL Server localdb database using `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` like this:

```
[Column(CanBeNull = false)]
private string FirstDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

[Column(CanBeNull = false)]
private string SecondDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

[Column(CanBeNull = false)]
private string ThirdDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

(I made them all private because I don't want anyone to access them directly outside the class, including me)

However, I have made a list that encapsulates them all. like this:

```
private List<DateTime> _dates;

public List<DateTime> Dates {
    get {
        var f    = DateTime.TryParse(FirstDate,  out var first);
        var s    = DateTime.TryParse(SecondDate, out var second);
        var t    = DateTime.TryParse(ThirdDate,  out var third);
        var list = new List<DateTime>();
        if (f) list.Add(first);
        if (s) list.Add(second);
        if (t) list.Add(third);
        if (_dates != null) return list;
        _dates = list;
        return list;
    }
    private set {
        FirstDate  = value[0].ToShortDateString();
        SecondDate = value[1].ToShortDateString();
        ThirdDate  = value[2].ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Then made a method to add dates to the list:

```
public void AddDate(DateTime date) {
    if (_dates == null) // this was added because some parts of `Dates` getter didn't work for some reason
        _dates = Dates;

    if (_dates.Count == 3)
        throw new ManyDatesException(); // custom exception

    if (_dates.Contains(date))
        return;

    _dates.Add(date);
}
```

Then save them all:

```
public void SaveDates() {
    // this saves data of `_dates` to the private fields using the setter of `Dates`
    Dates = _dates;
}
```

Then I would do the logic through various events and buttons in WPF:

```
private void AddDates_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var date = IDatePicker.SelectedDate ?? IDatePicker.DisplayDate;
    var datesClass = DatesProvider.GetDatesClass(1);
    var anotherDatesClass = DatesProvider.GetDatesClass(2);
    if (datesClass.Dates.Contains(date)) {
        Debug.Show(new DateAlreadyExistException()); // custom function for showing exception messages
        return;
    }

    try {
        datesClass.AddMonth(date);
    } catch (ManyDatesException ex) {
        Debug.Show(ex);
        return;
    }

    // save everything to the actual database
}
```

but I ran into a set of serious problems, some of them are:

- Click events get fired up more than once (Already unsubscribed and subscribed to the click event)
- Even after getting the public `Date` list and supposedly setting the private `_dates` there, `_dates` is still null and unassigned.
- Somehow, when firing the click event for the first time and assigning `_dates` in `AddDate(DateTime date)` it doesn't proceed to the rest of the method `AddDate()` but proceeds when `_dates` is already assigned.

This is so frustrating, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's probably frustrating because private properties are an odd concept. You may perhaps make them readonly, i.e. with a private setter.

Comment: That code is pretty convoluted. What exactly is the purpose of the class?

Comment: @Clemens I want to access the private properties as a list and save them as properties so they can actually get saved into the database because sql doesn't support arrays and such objects.

Comment: @RufusL retrieving and saving a punch of dates into an sql database using linq to sql.

Comment: But there's so much confusing logic there, it's hard to tell what the requirements are or why you're doing it this way.

Comment: With all the interesting logic in the getter and setter for `_dates`, it's hard to see why you even need that field at all. You may as well just return a new list populated from your 3 private properties on each get (which is actually what you're doing - you return `list` each time. What are the requirements for this class? Why three private string fields and a private dates list?

Comment: I have an ItemsSource in the app's UI side, and I wanted to populate it with dates, those dates are stored in the database using this particular class -- `DatesClass`--. but they are not stored as a list so I need to retrieve them as a list.

Comment: I created the public `Dates` list, which gets the actual dates stored in the database, and returns them as a list. In the UI part, I created some logic to add dates to that retrieved list. Finally, because I can't save lists to database directly, I need to modify the old dates fields so I created the public setter's logic.

Comment: The requirements are actually simple, give me a list of the stored dates, if the retrieved list is less than 3 -- less than the number of fields -- give the user the ability to add more dates to the list, and finally save those dates back to the private fields.

Comment: I imagine part of the problem is that in your `AddDate` method you add a date to your private list, but in the `get` method for `Dates`, you only return what's stored in the private fields. So `AddDate` doesn't really do anything useful because `_dates` is assigned to a new `list` in the `get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the problem is the fact that you're trying to coordinate 3 private fields and a private list, and there are times when either the list or a field get updated but not the other.

Based on your comments and the code you've shared, it doesn't seem that the private `List<DateTime> _dates` is really needed. It sounds like you only need to have 3 private properties (for data binding I guess?), you want to expose them as a list, and you want to provide a method to add dates.

If this is all true, then you should be able to encapsulate your fields without an actual private list behind the scenes:

```
public class DatesClass
{
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    private string FirstDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    private string SecondDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    private string ThirdDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<DateTime> Dates
    {
        get
        {
            var dates = new List<DateTime>();
            DateTime temp;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(FirstDate, out temp)) dates.Add(temp);
            if (DateTime.TryParse(SecondDate, out temp)) dates.Add(temp);
            if (DateTime.TryParse(ThirdDate, out temp)) dates.Add(temp);
            return dates;
        }
    }

    public void AddDate(DateTime date)
    {
        if (Dates.Contains(date)) return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstDate)) FirstDate = date.ToShortDateString();
        else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecondDate)) SecondDate = date.ToShortDateString();
        else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ThirdDate)) ThirdDate = date.ToShortDateString();
        else throw new ManyDatesException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Never thought of it so simple.